# collapse everything that goes into fun arg / ellipsis into a string

Tags: r, functional-programming

What has to go into my function `reg_sort`

So that call :

```
reg_sort(-"\\w","\\w$","\\d+")
```

returns: (**desired outcome**)

```
"-\"\\w\",\"\\w$\",\"\\d+\""
```

My function: (comments are my unsuccessful tries)

```
reg_sort <- function(...) {

    #reg_list <- toString(x=...)
    #reg_list <- substitute(...)
    #reg_list <- deparse(...)
    #reg_list <- deparse(substitute(...))
    #reg_list <- quote(...)
    #reg_list <- as.name(substitute(...))

    return(reg_list)
    }
```

Getting very close: (something like this would already work for me. If you have alternatives to share I'm glad to see)

```
reg_sort <- function(...) {
    reg_list <- toString(match.call()) %>% sub(".*?,","",.) %>% gsub("\\\\","\\",.,fixed=T) %>% trimws

    return(reg_list)
    }
reg_sort(-"\\w","\\w$","\\d+")
#[1] "-\"\\w\", \\w$, \\d+"
```

Comment: Do you need that minus sign? R will interpret it as an unary operator, therefore illegal.

Comment: hey, it's important. otherwise I would had easily used `reg_list <- list(...)`

Comment: Your rules for escaping are confusing me a bit. Are you showing the R output where slashes are escaped? Or did you want to keep the escape sequence as part of the string?

Comment: @MrFlick i have put `'-"\\w","\\w$","\\d+"'` into R console and considered this the desired output. With that i could work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returns the ellipsis arguments as a single, comma joined string.

```
reg_sort <- function(...) {
    ellipsis <- sapply(as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1], deparse, simplify="array")
    return(paste0(ellipsis, collapse=','))
}
```

Example:

```
> reg_sort( -"\\w", "\\w$", "\\d+")
[1] "-\"\\\\w\",\"\\\\w$\",\"\\\\d+\""
```

Note that the escaping in your desired output is incorrect - you need to escape backslash literals too. We can use `cat()` to see the underlying string without the additional layer of R escaping:

```
> cat(reg_sort( -"\\w", "\\w$", "\\d+"))
-"\\w","\\w$","\\d+"
```

We can see this is the original arguments, including the minus sign. Whitespace is irretrievable AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to pass the minus sign between double quotes, the following will do what you want.

```
reg_sort <- function(...){
  f <- function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = "\",\"")
  Reduce(f, list(...))
}

reg_sort("\\w","\\w$","\\d+")
#[1] "\\w\",\"\\w$\",\"\\d+"

reg_sort("-","\\w","\\w$","\\d+")
#[1] "-\",\"\\w\",\"\\w$\",\"\\d+"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But i would like to have the `-` infront of the string.